# Исходники на sourceforge.net

Tags: c++

Кто работал с исходниками sourceforge.net? В списках файла исходника числятся такие, как makefile.in ... как можно скомпилировать подобный исходник на Винде? Как я понял, судя по всему, подобные исходники рассчитаны для работы под Unix-системами, так ли это? Также присутствуют две папки src - в ней .h и .c файлы,  и папка man. Как быть? Спасибо!

Comment: Скомпилировать абстрактную программу навряд ли получится. Если программа заточена под линукс, то вполне может быть, что скомпилировать ее может и получится под виндой, а вот использовать - только под линуксом.

Comment: ее экзэшник вполне работает на винде, и в папке src  открываются файлы языка я, только вот скомпилировать невозможно, самого проекта нет...

Comment: Поставьте \*nix окружение (например Msys) на винду и работайте.

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/hyenae/files/0.36-1/ на этом адресе лежит данный исходник. помогите разобраться, может я чего до конца не понимаю... спасибо!

Comment: @Pentium, [там же](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hyenae/files/0.36-1/) все написано,  причем смотреть можно на месте, не скачивая.

А я вот чего не понимаю, зачем Вам это ? Спички детям не игрушка !

Comment: Да мне для диагностики сети на уязвимость к ДоС атакам надо программу написать, но только модифицируя, вот я и хотел взять для этого Hyenae... а че там написано то? в исходнике не могу разобраться... вроде на С написана... каким компилятором или еще чем либо может вспомогательным открывать надо.... я работаю на Винде, в визуал студио 2005...

Answer (score 3):

Под фразой "самого проекта нет" понимается отсутствие файла проекта, который бы Вы открыли в своей IDE (VisualStudio), так? Файл проекта, грубо говоря, содержит сведения, необходимые интегрированной среде для корректной работы с файлами исходного кода, ресурсами, формами и т.п. Вы включили новый файл исходного кода - в файл проекта IDE добавляет запись. Основываясь на файле проекта, IDE генерирует файл сборки Makefile, исполняя правила которого программа make вызывает необходимые утилиты - компиляторы, компоновщики и т.п.

Файл сборки (Makefile) можно написать и вручную, но часто он получается громоздким. В мире GNU для автоматизации генерирования Makefile используют вспомогательные утилиты autoconf/automake. С их помощью, в частности, и создан шаблон Makefile.in в рассматриваемом проекте, а также сценарий (скрипт) configure.

Последовательность действий такова:

1. Ставите MinGW/MSys или Cygwin (лучше первый - меньше зависимостей)
2. Открываете консоль MSys
3. Переходите в предварительно распакованную папку проекта
4. Запускаете скрипт configure командой ./configure
5. Если все в порядке, в каталоге будет построен файл Makefile
6. Запускаете make командой make
7. Если все в порядке, в каталоге src будет построен исполняемый файл .exe
8. Переходите в src, запускаете .exe или выполняете команду make install и запуск .exe будет возможен из любого каталога в консоли MSys.

На шаге 4, скрипт configure может начать ругаться на отсутствие тех или иных возможностей компилятора или сторонних библиотек (MSys содержит минимальный набор). Можно пробовать искать исходники зависимостей и устанавливать описанным выше способом.

Для запуска вне консоли MSys потребуются некоторые библиотеки (при попытке запуска увидите сообщение о том, чего не хватает), например, mingw-10.dll. Их можно найти в дебрях каталогов установки MinGW и MSys.

В любом случае, следует запастись терпением и бубном. Удачи.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, сейчас попробую...